# What is the proper way to shut down ICp?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I have an ICp installation on some bare metal to educate myself with.  So I don't need to keep it running all the time.  What is the proper way to shut it down while I am not using it?  I have two physical nodes; master and worker.  Currently I just `ssh` into each and issue a `sudo shutdown now` command.

When I bring the cluster back on line later, the I can't get to the admin UI.  It responds with a 502 bad gateway error. When I load https://master:9443 I get the Welcome to Liberty page (indicating that at least the web server is running).

Comment: depends on the ICP version, check this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.2/manage_cluster/restart_cluster.html

Answer (score 6):

If you stop docker containers or the docker runtime, then the kubelet will attempt to restart them.

If you want to shutdown the system, you must stop the kubelet on each node. On Ubuntu, you would use `systemctl`:

```
sudo systemctl stop kubelet
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

Confirm that all processes are shutdown:

```
top
```

And that all related network ports are no longer in use:

```
netstat -antp
```

(Note that `netstat`'s "-p" option requires root privileges to inspect the pid holding onto the port).

To restart the cluster, start `docker` and then the `kubelet`. Again for Ubuntu:

```
sudo start docker
sudo start kubelet
```

And of course you can follow the logs for the `kubelet`:

```
sudo journalctl -e -u kubelet
```

Comment: Should the start commands be `sudo systemctl start docker` and `sudo systemctl start kubelet` ?

Answer (score -1):

Stop Docker to shut it down, I hope this helped.

`systemctl stop docker`